# Running a C Server on Mac. How to Connect to it on Terminal for debugging purposes.

Tags: c, macos, sockets, networking

Suppose I've managed to get the server up and running by executing:

./foo [portno] [args]

How do I telnet into the server on the local machine?

I tried the following:

1. telnet localhost [portno] 
   ERROR: localhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
2. telnet [portno]
   ERROR: Trying 0.1.226.65...
   telnet: connect to address 0.1.226.65: No route to host
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 [portno]
```

You should have something like the following in your `/private/etc/hosts` in order for `localhost` to work:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Also, make sure that you run `telnet 127.0.0.1 123` and not `telnet 127.0.0.1:123` (where `123` is the port).

Comment: tried it. Doens't work.
I checked the hosts doc too. Localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1

Comment: try `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: 127.0.0.1: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
@ctn

Comment: In the System Preferences go into Network and check that you have a loopback interface and that it is enabled.

Comment: where do i find this in Mountain Lion? I've searched advanced and everywhere else. There is no such option.

Comment: Try executing `ifconfig -l` in a Terminal and post the output somewhere (e.g.: gist.github.com).

Comment: Try `sudo ifconfig lo0 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 up`

Comment: nope. Doesn't work as well. 
Still 127.0.0.1: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: Assuming port is `123` you're doing `telnet 127.0.0.1 123` ?

Comment: yes. I am doing that. Also on a side note, this same program worked on Solaris.